# How to localize the whole java spring application

Tags: java, spring, localization

I know about standard way to localize java spring application with adding ?lang=en(fr, de, ch), but it is localize only one page, than after move to other page (press on any href="/newpage"), there again default locale, not choosen before. My question is: how i can ot determinate at login page (or index page) user locale and set it as default locale for the whole web application?

**Update question 14.02.2014-16:32 
Addition information.**

Default spring implementation of localization it is adding "?lang=en" to request URI and takes new messages from bundle. So there is an example:
default locale set to en
uri: http://example.com/index - en locale. 
uri: http://example.com/index?lang=de - German Locale setted - page translated to German.
But than, i click on the link, which got href="/profile". When i clicked:
uri: http://example.com/profile - i got default locale - en.

What i want:
uri: http://example.com/index - user press on German flag in the top of the site, than some bean get this action and set default locale - German. Than all pages will loading with default german locale.
uri: http://example.com/profile - default locale - German.

In uri request example, i want something like that:
example.com - detect user locale - set default locale, German for an example/
User press on English flag - default locale set to English for all pages.

**Update question 14.02.2014-17:38
Addition information. Information about my mistake**
Everything is good. I marked right answer. Spring standard implementation works great and exactly i want. I got mistake in JSP pages with not full translate, and when i change locale, i though that not everything translated - but it was. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring Documentation is very well for this theme: [17.8 Using locales](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver)
You need two things:

- A [`LocalResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html) - that is holds the local for an user and when the user send a request, it add the local to the request context (available via `RequestContext.getLocale()`) - often the [`SessionLocalResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/SessionLocaleResolver.html) or [`CookieLocaleResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/CookieLocaleResolver.html) is used for a normal web page based application - it is **important that the bean id/name is `localeResolver`** (`DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER_BEAN_NAME="localeResolver"`) - (if the name is different, then `DispatcherServlet` will not find the locale resolver !
- A [`LocaleChangeInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html) that change the locale when the user add `?lang=de` to its request.

example configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
      id="localeResolver"
      name="localeResolver">        
   <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

<mvc:interceptors>
     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
           p:paramName="lang">          
     </bean>
     ...
</mvc:interceptors>
```

*For your problem, it is likely that something with the `LocalResolver` is wrong, maybe you just forget to set its id/name* to `localeResolver` or you use a `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` (that always "fall back" the the request header locale)*

** see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/874515/280244) for the difference between Id and Name*