# How can a Spring bean get its own id (not name)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

`BeanNameAware` interface allows me to access the name of a bean after its creation inside it. But I need the id of that bean. This is needed to differentiate between prototype scope beans as BeanNameAware provides me the same names in all the instances created in prototype scope.

Update:

If this is not possible, is there any other way to differentiate between instances created under the prototype scope after creation?

The problem I am trying to solve:

I have a class `A<?>` which is a prototype scoped bean. This class needs different `?`s at different points of time. Say, I used the prototype nature of the bean to create two different instances of `A<?>`, which are `A<B>` and `A<C>`. I have to provide their ids to a mbean exporter, so that I could inspect their state at runtime. But I am not able to get their ids.

Comment: Actually I have never heard that each instance of prototype bean is having an (inspectable) ID.  Mind to point out such concept in any Spring document?  Bean ID has long been almost an synonym of Bean Name (with some minor difference)

Comment: I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874505/difference-between-using-bean-id-and-name-in-spring-configuration-file. Although there is no mention that a spring bean id would be unique across prototype instances, I wanted to try it out if any such thing exists because names of those instances are the same. So is there any other way to differentiate between instances created of a class in prototype scope after their creation?

Comment: If you look carefully in the question you quote, `id` is not for identifying multiple instances (created base on misc scope) of same bean.  TBH I have never encounter any case that you need to differentiate prototype beans and I am suspecting it is an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) .  Would you mind telling the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sure. I have a class A<?> which is a prototype scoped bean. This class needs different ?s at different points of time. Say, I used the prototype nature of the bean to create two different instances of A<?>, which are A<B> and A<C>. I have to provide their ids to a mbean exporter, so that I could inspect their state at runtime. But I am not able to get their ids.

Comment: It looks strange to me that you are exposing prototype bean as MBean.  "Different `?` (I believe you mean type-arg of generic) does not seems a reason for using prototype bean.  If you just want a unique ID, can't you just make it up by UUID?

Comment: Why do you find it strange? Any bean could be exposed as a mbean. Whether or not it is a prototype bean is not relevant to that. My design should not be dictated by the limitations of Spring. I find it intuitive to have different A<?>s in my code, each adapting to its own role according to its generic type. Any other UUID could work, but mbean export requires bean id, or so I think.